# Confusion about how char *s and char s[] works at low level

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I know similar questions, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s), have been posted and answered here but those answers don't offer me the complete picture, hence I'm posting this as a new question. Hope that is ok.

See following snippets -

```
char s[9] = "foobar";  //ok
s[1] = 'z'             //also ok
```

And

```
char s[9];
s = "foobar"   //doesn't work. Why?
```

But see following cases -

```
char *s = "foobar";      //works
s[1] = 'z';              //doesn't work
char *s;
s = "foobar";            //unlike arrays, works here
```

It is a bit confusing. I mean I have vague understanding that we can't assign values to arrays. But we can modify it. In case of `char *s`, it seems we can assign values but can't modify it because it is written in read only memory. But still I can't get the full picture.

What exactly is happening at low level?

Comment: If it was possible...imagine `char s[9]; s = "123"; s[0] = 'a';`.

Comment: It might help to imagine that, for every string literal (e.g. `"foobar"`) the compiler would automatically put a definition like `const char string_literal_001[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'};` somewhere else, and what you actually did was `s = string_literal_001;` for a simple assignment or `strcpy(s, string_literal_001)` for an initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char s[9] = "foobar";` This is *initialization*. An array of characters of size 9 is declared and then its contents receives the string `"foobar"` with any remaining characters set to `'\0'`.

`s = "foobar"` is just *invalid C syntax*. You cannot assign a string to a char array. To make `s` have the value `foobar`. Use `strcpy(s,"foobar");`

`char *s = "foobar";` is also initialization, however, this assigns the *address* of the constant string `foobar` to the *pointer variable* `s`. Note that I say "constant string". A string literal is on most platforms constant. A better way of making this clear is to write `const char *s = "foobar";`

And indeed, your next assignment `s[1]= 'z';` will not work because `s` is constant.

Comment: I guess I need to better understand what "initialization" and "assignment" mean. As for `s = "foobar"` being invalid syntax, the compiler actually complains that `error: array type 'char [9]' is not assignable
s = "foobar"`.

Comment: Whenever you _declare_ a variable, you can _initialize_ it. That is compile-time. Any other use of `=` is _assignment_ which is run-time.

Comment: Can you or someone else please expand on "You cannot assign a string to char array." part?

Comment: That is helpful. I really didn't think about that part.

Comment: "Assigning a string to a char array" means that every char of the string must be assigned to the corresponding char of the array. All those instructions are _not_ automatically generated by the C compiler. However, to do just that, there is the library function `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what the expressions are actually doing, then it might come clear to you.

1. `char s[9] = "foobar";` -> *Initialize* the `char` array `s` by the string literal `"foobar"`. Correct.
2. `s[1] = 'z'` -> Assign the character constant `'z'` to the second elem. of `char` array `s`. Correct.
3. `char s[9]; s = "foobar";` -> Declare the `char` array `a`, then attempt to *assign* the string literal `"foobar"` to the `char` array. Not permissible. You can´t actually assign arrays in C, you can only *initialize* an array of `char` with a string when defining the array itself. That´s the difference. If you want to copy a string into an array of `char` use `strcpy(s, "foobar");` instead.
4. `char *s = "foobar";`  -> Define the pointer to `char` `s` and initialize it to point to the string literal `"foobar"`. Correct.
5. `s[1] = 'z';` -> Attempt to modify the string literal `"foobar"`, to which is `s` pointing to. Not permissible. A string literal is stored in read-only memory.
6. `char *s; s = "foobar";` -> Declare the pointer to `char` `s`. Then assign the pointer to point to the string literal `"foobar"`. Correct.

Answer (score 1):

This declares array `s` with an *initializer*:

```
char s[9] = "foobar";  //ok
```

But this is an invalid *assignment* expression with array `s` on the left:

```
s = "foobar";   //doesn't work. Why?
```

Assignment expressions and declarations with initializers are not the same thing syntactically, although they both use an `=` in their syntax.

The reason that the assignment to the array `s` doesn't work is that the array decays to a pointer to its first element in the expression, so the assignment is equivalent to:

```
&(s[0]) = "foobar";
```

The assignment expression requires an *lvalue* on the left hand side, but the result of the `&` address operator is not an *lvalue*. Although the array `s` itself is an *lvalue*, the expression converts it to something that isn't an *lvalue*.  Therefore, an array cannot be used on the left hand side of an assignment expression.

---

For the following:

```
char *s = "foobar";      //works
```

The string literal `"foobar"` is stored as an anonymous array of `char` and as an *initializer* it decays to a pointer to its first element.  So the above is equivalent to:

```
char *s = &(("foobar")[0]);      //works
```

The initializer has the same type as `s` (`char *`) so it is fine.

For the subsequent assignment:

```
s[1] = 'z';              //doesn't work
```

It is *syntactically* correct, but it violates a constraint, resulting in *undefined behavior*.  The constraint that is being violated is that the anonymous arrays created by string literals are *not modifiable*.  Assignment to an element of such an array is a *modification* and not allowed.

The subsequent assignment:

```
s = "foobar";            //unlike arrays, works here
```

is equivalent to:

```
s = &(("foobar")[0]);            //unlike arrays, works here
```

It is assigning a `char *` value to a variable of type `char *`, so it is fine.

---

Contrast the following use of the initializer `"foobar"`:

```
char *s = "foobar";      //works
```

with its use in the earlier declaration:

```
char s[9] = "foobar";  //ok
```

There is a special initialization rule that allows an array of `char` to be initialized by a string literal optionally enclosed by braces.  That initialization rule is being used to initialize `char s[9]`.

The string literal used to initialize the array also creates an anonymous array of `char` (at least notionally) but there is no way to access that anonymous array of `char`, so it may get omitted from the output of the compiler. This is in contrast with the anonymous array of `char` created by the string literal used to initialize `char *s` which *can* be accessed via `s`.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to think of C as not allowing you to do anything with arrays except for assisting in a few special cases. C originated when programming languages did little more than help you move individual bytes and “words” (2 or maybe 4 bytes) around and do simple arithmetic and operations with them. With that in mind, let’s look at your examples:

> `char s[9] = "foobar";  //ok`

This is one of the special cases: When you define an array of characters, the compiler will help you initialize it. In a definition, you may provide a string literal, which represents an array of characters, and the compiler will initialize your array with the contents of the string literal.

> `s[1] = 'z'             //also ok`

Yes, this just moves the value of one character into one array element.

> `char s[9];
>   s = "foobar"   //doesn't work. Why?`

This does not work because there is no assistance here. `s` and `"foobar"` are both arrays, but C has no provision for handling an array as one whole object.

However, although C does not handle an array as a whole object, it does provide some assistance for working with arrays. Since the compiler would not work with whole arrays, programmers needed some other ways to work with arrays. So C was given a feature that, when you used an array in an expression, the compiler would automatically convert it to a pointer to the first element of the array, and that would help the programmer write code to work with elements of the array. We see that in your next example:

> `char *s = "foobar";      //works`

`char *s` declares `s` to be a pointer to `char`. Next, the string literal `"foobar"` represents an array. Above, we saw that using a string literal to initialize an array was a special case. However, here the string literal is not used to initialize an array. It is used to initialize a pointer, so the special case rules do not apply. In this case, the array represented by the string literal is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. So `s` is initialized to be a pointer to the first element of the array containing “f”, “o”, “o”, “b”, “a”, “r”, and a null character.

> `s[1] = 'z';              //doesn't work`

The arrays defined by string literals are intended to be constants. They are “read-only” in the sense that the C standard does not define what happens when you try to modify them. In many C implementations, they are assigned to memory that is read-only because the operating system and the computer hardware do not allow writing to it by normal program means. So `s[1] = 'z';` may get an exception (trap) or a warning or error message from the compiler. (Ideally, `char *s = "foobar";` would be disallowed because `"foobar"`, being a constant, would have type `const char [7]`. However, because `const` did not exist in early C, the types of string literals do not have `const`.)

> `char *s;
>   s = "foobar";            //unlike arrays, works here`

Here `s` is a `char *`, and the string literal `"foobar"` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer is a `char *`, so the assignment is fine.